# Tips on preparing a good slideshow talk

Tags: mathematics, presentation, science

I am preparing a talk for an advanced graduate course in mathematics, where I am supposed to use slides (the Beamer type, not handwritten).

Since it's the first time I'm giving a presentation talk as opposed to a blackboard talk, I was wondering whether any of you have some advice on preparing a good presentation, and presenting it (in particular, if you come from a scientific background).

Thanks!

Comment: See [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/inspiration-for-great-presentations) for tips on preparing slides, [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/how-to-do-a-flawless-and-natural-presentation) for tips on presenting them. I believe we've already covered *general* presentation tips here, but if you have a *specific* question that isn't addressed in those other posts, please [edit] your question to highlight it and it may be reopened.