# How to organize content of slides for a conference presentation?

Tags: conference, presentation

I am going to attend my first IEEE conference on Electronic Design/Verification and am feeling quite nervous about my first oral presentation.

I want to make sure to "sell" my point and ensure all questions are being tackled, and so I am looking for advice related to the organization of my slides. For example,

- How can the slide material  complement my speaking?
- How do I ensure that the end-product is not dry/heavy?
- If my work is on for example, SRAM or Post-silicon technologies,is it recommended to begin my presentation with a foil on a collage of the latest news snippets about these topics? This could probably draw their attention rather than picking up some lines from my camera-ready's introduction section.
- Also, how many slides should I ideally allocate for each section of my paper?

I am forced to ask such "trivial" questions as my Professor is on a sabbatical currently and has little/no access to mail for the next few weeks. 
I have searched the Internet and found some generic advice, like ["How to give a bad talk"](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~pattrsn/talks/BadTalk.pdf) by David Patterson.

There are some related questions on this site that do not seem to directly address how to organize the content of the slides. [How to do a flawless and natural presentation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17984/how-to-do-a-flawless-and-natural-presentation) asks about becoming a more effective orator. [Inspiration for great presentations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/inspiration-for-great-presentations) asks about effective design elements (not content organization) for slides.

Comment: ... I am a huge fan of Latex. Just do not use it for presentations. You can use the PDF export of TEX on a full screen, which is also universally supported everywhere.

Comment: Note: removed no-longer relevant meta comments related to previous versions of this post

Comment: Edited my question to differentiate from the linked one.

Comment: I removed some vestiges of the old post that no longer seem directly relevant to the focus of the new question, and reopened. Good luck with your presentation :)

Comment: I just stumbled upon this [question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/should-the-slides-in-a-presentation-be-self-explanatory-or-be-as-minimal-as-poss). I wanted to know if it is wrong in requesting experts in that forum to post an example of their/others' presentation and the associated conference paper. More than advice, I am looking at a "template" for my presentation.

Comment: @ff524, Please let me know why this question is still not being attended to.

Comment: A new question asking for examples of presentations and their associated papers would be off topic (per the [help/dont-ask]), and would be closed. But you *could* ask in [chat] if anyone has any they would like to share there. As for why this question hasn't gotten more answers; nobody is *obligated* to answer any question. It seems that nobody has chosen to answer this one. You could post a link to this question in chat also - that might help draw attention to it.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that the question was closed. That is why I needed some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to finish early than late (if they would let you). Do not
try to say too much. Then try to be informal, to give a feeling and
intuitive understanding for what you are doing. If you include an
equation, you probably want to explain it informally. It is often unlikely
that most people will follow details that are too technical.

Part, or all, of the presentation is really advertising for the
paper. Make then understand the concepts, and why it is interesting
and new. But you should probably skip the technical details of proofs
or programs.  However, relating your work to existing work is
important: the audience will want to understand why they should spend
time reading you paper, what advances they will get beyond what they
already know.  If they are interested in a specific detail they
consider crucial, they will as a question. But you are unlikely to
know in advance what it will be.

Remember, you will not tell your whole paper in one talk. Else the
talk would be longer, or the paper shorter.

If you think that some details are important and that you may have
question about them, though they would overload your talk, you can
prepare slides to answer questions about them. And you use them if
needed.  But do not mix them with the other slides, put them at the
end.

Your PDF (PDF is generally accepted) should be organized so that you do not have to think about it
during the talk. You will be busy enough.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have some examples regarding the advertising part? If you can provide links to papers and publications by undergraduate researchers, it would be of great help.

Comment: @AgrimRaghav I wrote on the basis of personal experience. No precise example available. What I mean is that you have to put forward the key ideas that make your work interesting, with enough details to be credible, but not more than people can swallow in the alloted time, after attending many other technical presentations. What matters may be dependent on topic. Relating to previous work is needed, but then your work may be interesting for the result, for the techniques used to get it, for the potential applications, or possibly for its new perspectives on the problems (rare, but important).